# Why are my concurrent AJAX requests to PHP Scripts/WP REST API so slow?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, rest

**After some investigation, I updated the title of the question. Please see my updates below.**

*Original question:*

I'm building a website with Wordpress and make sometimes use of async calls to WP REST API endpoints.

Calling this endpoints from my AJAX functions leads often to TTFB times from at least ~780ms:

[image]

But if I open the URL/endpoint directly in the browser I get TTFB times that are 4-5 time faster:

[image]

I wonder where the delays come frome. I'm running this page on my local dev server with Apache 2.4, HTTP/2 and PHP 7 enabled.

What is the best way to monitor such performance "issues"?

**Please mind:** I'm **not** using Wordpress' built-in AJAX-functionality. I'm just calling something like

```
axios.get(`${url}/wp-json/wp/v2/flightplan`)
```

inside a React component that I've mounted in my homepage-template.

## Update

Damn interesting: clearing cookies reduces TTFB **a lot**:

[image]

## Update 2

After removing the other both AJAX calls, the `flightplan` request performs much faster. I think there are some issues with concurrent AJAX requests. I've read a bit about sessions locking, but since Wordpress and all of the installed plugins doesn't make use of sessions, this can't be the reason.

## Update 3

Definitively, it has something to do with my local server setup. Just deployed the site to a "real" webserver:

[image]

But it would still be interesting to know how to setup a server that can handle concurrent better.

## Update 4

I made a little test: calling 4 dummy-requests before calling the "real" ones. The script only returns a "Foobar" string. Everything looks fine at this time:

[image]

But when adding `sleep(3)` to the dummy AJAX-script, all other requests takes much longer too:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 3):

Because your Ajax call will wait the loading of all your WP plugins :)

So you need to make some test without plugin, and activate one by one to see which one slow down your ajax call.

Comment: There are just a few WP plugins activated (MultilingualPress, ACF, ACF to REST and Timber), and all of them are necessary for the right output of my REST API calls (ok, beside Timber). But I don't understand the difference between my AJAX call, that just fetches the contents of `example.com/rest/foo` and directly accessing `example.com/rest/foo`.

Comment: Just created a fiddle (outside any WP environment) and made an AJAX call to an endpoint. Same speed as accessing directly. So Wordpress seems to modify/filter/whatever AJAX request?

Comment: When you use ajax in wordpress you need hooks, so you load all the wordpress mechanics, so it will be slower for sure.

Comment: I don't do any hooks? I'm just calling `$.ajax({...})` inside my JS functions.

Comment: It's just `axios.get(\`${$('meta[name="site-url"]').attr('content')}/wp-json/wp/v2/flightplan\`)`

Comment: if you make the $.ajax call without the axios promise its better ?

Comment: I'm using `axios` instead of `$.ajax`. Tried `$.ajax` also, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: I just read some stuff on that, on the way you do the ajax call will load all the wordpress (header sidebar footer plugin....) stuff. maybe you can try using [WordPress REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/). But keep in mind, ajax in wordpress is only for filtering stuff, having an endpoint without wordpress will always be faster

Comment: As the title of this question says, I'm using WP REST API already :)